# how to grant access of local file system to Wildfly server

Tags: java, tomcat7, fileoutputstream, wildfly-8

I am trying to write a file in Java. I am using simple "FileOutputStream". My application is deployed on "**WildFly 8.0 Runtime Server**"

**My code is:**

> FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new
>   File("c:/newfile.txt"));

**I am getting an exception:**

> 19:24:36,235 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\newfile.txt (Access is denied)
>
> 19:24:36,237 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)  at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
>
> 19:24:36,239 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)  at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:221)
>
> 19:24:36,240 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)  at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:171)
>
> 19:24:36,240 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)  at
>   com.ews.angualrspringapp.controller.SelfieController.processImage(SelfieController.java:122)
>
> 19:24:36,241 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> 19:24:36,241 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>
> 19:24:36,242 ERROR [stderr] (default task-8)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

My this code is working fine with **Apache Tomcat v7.0 Server**.